# get table information using feching table in mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Help....

I have 2 tables,

customers

```
id | registration_code | full_name
 1 | A01               | ABC
 2 | B01               | BCD
 3 | C01               | CDE
 4 | D01               | DEF
```

history_transaction

```
id | customer_id | transaction_date
 1 | 1           | 2015-01-01
 2 | 2           | 2015-01-01
 3 | 3           | 2015-01-01
 4 | 1           | 2015-01-02
 5 | 3           | 2015-01-02
 6 | 1           | 2015-01-03
```

I use PHP, and I want to get a customer list and transaction times between 2015-01-01 till 2015-01-03

the result should be

```
id | registration_code | full_name | n_trans
 1 | A01               | ABC       | 3
 2 | B01               | BCD       | 1
 3 | C01               | CDE       | 2
```

Please help. I want to use Store Procedure on MySQL, and I dont want to loop it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the info you use a group by statement:

```
SELECT a.id,a.registration_code,a.full_name, COUNT(*) as n_trans
FROM customers a
INNER JOIN history_transaction b 
ON a.id=b.customer_id
WHERE b.transaction_date BETWEEN "{start_date}" AND "{end_date}"
GROUP BY a.id,a.registration_code,a.full_name;
```

You can set start_date and end_date dynamically using mysqli (a php module for working with MySQL from php).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to create stored procedure in MySQL:

CREATE PROCEDURE find_transaction_detail()
BEGIN
    SELECT a.id,a.registration_code,a.full_name, COUNT(*) as n_trans
    FROM customers a
    INNER JOIN history_transaction ON a.id=b.customer_id
    WHERE b.transaction_date BETWEEN "{start_date}" AND "{end_date}"
    GROUP BY a.id,a.registration_code,a.full_name;
END;

Way to find result:

CALL find_transaction_detail ();